# Transferring from Database to django dropbox

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to fill a dropbox with values from my database using Django and HTML. I have been trying to figure out how for hours but it is not updating.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select id = "classChoice" >
    <option value = "base"> ----- </option>
    {% for class.name in objectlist %}
    <option value = "class.name"> {{ class.name }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
class searchPageForm(forms.Form):
    className = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Classroom.objects.all())
    studentName = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    studentID = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here is the views.py:

```
def search(request):
    form = searchPageForm()
    if request.GET.get('class.name'):
        featured_filter = request.GET.get('class.name')
        objectlist = searchPageForm.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'pollingSite/search.html', {'objectlist': objectlist})
    else: 
        classNames = Classroom.objects.filter(instructor = request.user)
        return render(request, 'pollingSite/search.html', locals())
```

I am stuck and have tried everything and it's just not populating.

Answer (score 1):

In your html page, the `{% for object in objectlist %}` means that it will iterate over the `objectlist` and assign each object in the list to `object`. This means that you can access the attributes of `Classroom` using the instance `object`. So change the html as follows:

```
<select id="classChoice">
<option value = "base"> ----- </option>
    {% for object in objectlist %}      <!-- You were making mistake here -->
        <option value = "{{ object.id }}"> {{ object.name }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And in your forms.py:

```
class searchPageForm(forms.Form):
    className = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    studentName = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    studentID = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```